# Sort table listings first by Date then by priority (Django)

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models

I am building a tasker application where items are sorted first by Date/Time due then each section of items due on the same date are re-sorted by priority.

I know how to sort items by date-time, but how do I go about re-sorting each subsection again.

Priority is an integer from 0-9.

Sorry that I don't have any code to submit, I am still working through the design to how I will code my models.

I couldn't find any items related on google (or I don't know how to word the query)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queryset `order_by()` method [accepts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) multiple arguments:

```
models.MyModel.objects.order_by('date_field', 'priority')
```

Comment: Thanks! That was simple!